# Firebase Cloud Storage: 'UploadTask' undefined class

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an Image using ImagePicker to CloudStorage but for some reason UploadTask is being stated as undefinied.

Am I missing something here or it's just the frequent updates to firebase features that got me lost here?

[image]

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as FirebaseStorage;


FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Submit',
              ),
              onPressed: () async {    
                FirebaseStorage.FirebaseStorage storage =
                    FirebaseStorage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
                FirebaseStorage.Reference refer = storage.ref(filePath);
                final File _myImage = File(_image.path);
                await refer.putFile(_myImage);
                *UploadTask uploadTask = refer.putFile(_myImage);*
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Please edit the question and copy into it the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem, including the import.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the notice. lemme know incase further edits are needed.

Comment: That's not the complete code.  Show the entire file, including the import.  Remove all the unnecessary code from that file that doesn't affect the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imported as "FirebaseStorage", then you need to use that identifier to declare your objects, as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#handling-tasks).

```
FirebaseStorage.UploadTask uploadTask = refer.putFile(_myImage);
```